# SQL Select exact matches to multiple items with duplicate ID's

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select someone who speaks the exact same languages (French, Italian, and Russian) from this table. It should obviously return just Maja:

```
PERSON     LANG     
---------- ----------
Ann        English   
Ann        Japanese  
Bill       English   
Bill       Japanese  
Bill       Russian   
Chris      English   
Chris      Russian   
David      English   
David      Japanese  
David      Russian   
Ernie      English   
Ernie      French    
Ernie      Japanese  
Fumie      Japanese  
Fumie      Korean    
Maja       French    
Maja       Italian   
Maja       Russian
```

The code I have understandably doesn't work since the names are duplicated and this query returns 0 results:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT PERSON
FROM SPEAKS
WHERE LANG = 'French'
AND LANG = 'Russian'
AND LANG = 'Italian';
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure out how to deal with these duplicate names.

Comment: you can't use and for multiple selections with "=".. since if lang is 'french' it definitely cant be the others.. so use "OR" or IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT PERSON
FROM SPEAKS
WHERE LANG IN( 'French', 'Russian', 'Italian')
GROUP BY PERSON
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LANG) = 3
```

The `DISTINCT` inside the `COUNT` is only needed in case you can have duplicates, i.e. the same language related to a person more than one time.